# GZip decompression in JavaScript with offset

Tags: javascript, c#, gzip

An API that I am trying to use is returning base64 encoded responses. The response is first compressed using GZip with 4 bits of offset and then base64 encoded. I tried parsing the response using JavaScript ([pako](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pako) and [zlib](http://npm%20i%20zlib)) and in both cases, it failed. The API has an example of C# code on how should the response decompression work, but I don't really know how can I transform that into JavaScript. So can anyone give me a hand transforming this function into JavaScript or just give me some tips on how to handle the 4 bytes offset? I didn't find anything relevant in the libraries' documentation.

```
public string Decompress(string value)
{
  byte[] gzBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    int msgLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(gzBuffer, 0);
    ms.Write(gzBuffer, 4, gzBuffer.Length - 4);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[msgLength];
    ms.Position = 0;
    using (System.IO.Compression.GZipStream zip = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
      zip.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
    return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
   }
}
```

Comment: Wait, so a unicode string is gzip'd (making it smaller) then base64'd (making it larger), then returned in a http response (which could have been gzip'd instead)? Yikes (https://www.osnews.com/story/19266/wtfsm/).

Comment: zip.Read doesn't promise to actually read length bytes, if you followed their example you could create a string containing a bunch of trailing zeros.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yeah, that was my interpretation of their decompression method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to use [fflate](https://github.com/101arrowz/fflate) (disclaimer, I'm the author) to do this. If you want to translate that function line for line:

```js
// This is ES6 code; if you want better browser compatibility
// use the ES5 variant.
import { gunzipSync, strToU8, strFromU8 } from 'fflate';
const decompress = str => {
  // atob converts Base64 to Latin-1
  // strToU8(str, true) converts Latin-1 to binary
  const bytes = strToU8(atob(str), true);
  // subarray creates a new view on the same memory buffer
  // gunzipSync synchronously decompresses
  // strFromU8 converts decompressed binary to UTF-8
  return strFromU8(gunzipSync(bytes.subarray(4)));
}
```

If you don't know what ES6 is:

In your HTML file:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fflate/umd/index.js"></script>
```

In your JS:

```js
var decompress = function(str) {
  var bytes = fflate.strToU8(atob(str), true);
  return fflate.strFromU8(fflate.gunzipSync(bytes.subarray(4)));
}
```

I'd like to mention that streams are almost totally useless if you're going to accumulate into a string at the end, so the C# code is suboptimal. At the same time, since you're using the standard library, it is the only option.

In addition, I'd highly recommend using the callback variant (i.e. `gunzip` instead of `gunzipSync`) if possible because that runs on a separate thread to avoid causing the browser to freeze.